# Desperate help in newton’s law cooling

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, exponential-function, physics

I’m a high school student that is attempting to explore the math involved behind newton’s law of cooling. I have tried to derive the equation and the idea was to apply it to a crime scene and finding the values of change in temperature and time. I talked to my teacher about this math exploration for her opinion on the difficulty of the math involved. Her answer was it is quite simple and I should integrate more math that maybe a bit more difficult that should be within my level of mathematics which in this case is higher math but the problem is I have no clue what else could be added into this law. In conclusion, if it would be possible to give me inspiration of what math I could involve that might be slightly harder than just deriving the equation to make my explorations slightly more difficult but stay within the difficulty of a high school student.

Comment: Does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling

Comment: Also, have you done any calculus yet in school?

Comment: Thank you very much for the source and yes we do calculus in school so if you have any recommendations please let me know.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really help you myself. I'm a high school student too. Perhaps the Physics SE site will be able to help you more. I;m just wondering; is the law based only on experimental evidence or can it be derived mathematucally from other known facts?

Comment: You may want to consider to take advantage of some recent developments in written language (interpunction, paragraphs) and especially in the language of mathematics (formulas). The latter would also give more information about your mathematical skills than just "high school".